# Flash AS3 Make object tween from side

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I have a game which is 800*600. Within the game I display a "dialog" in the center which is 354*400. I want to have a smaller message box type (233*143) tween in from the right side of the dialog to the center.
I thought I can just move the message box to the right but it actually has to be out of the 800*600 for it to not be seen.
What I really want is for it to look like it came from the right side of my dialog and not across the entire screen.

I hope this makes sense.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making it a child of your dialog asset, then setting it's x position accordingly? `smallerbox.x = dialog.width - smallerbox.width`?

Comment: Thanks but that still does the same thing

Comment: I'm assuming either your question lacks vital information regarding the positioning of your boxes, or you did not implement my suggestion correctly. Assuming you added the smaller box to your dialog box and placed it at the aforementioned position, then your message box would be coming "...from the right side of my dialog and not across the entire screen" almost exactly as you requested.

Comment: I did do as you suggested. It looks like there is something else going on. The dialog is 354 wide (I get this by clicking on the object in the designer and looking at the width). At runtime when I do a trace of the wide it prints 595.4. I tried setting the width in code as well to 354 but it remains 595.4. I must be missing something that's keeping it so wide.

Comment: That is a different issue than just getting it to appear from the right side of your dialog box. Check to make sure you aren't scaling the stage or parent of the object.